# Posting fom sap ui5 to external Custom API

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

Please help as I am stuck. I am unable to post to external API which was created. But when I try through Postman its working fine.

But when I try to perform the same in SAP UI5 it says:

> HTTP Status 500 - HTTP protocol error occurred while connecting to remote host https://sap_community-app_jp.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com. Reason: URI does not specify a valid host name: https:/calculate_json.

When I call the same URL through browser:

> Error: 404 Not Found
>
> Sorry, the requested URL 'https://sap_community-app_jp.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/' caused an error:

Need suggestions and inputs on the same.

Comment: "https:/calculate_json" does not look like a valid host name, I totally agree with the debbuger :D

Comment: UI5 apps requires a destination to be defined when calling external APIs